# Intersecting a set with an arbitrary union

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I want to verify that my proof is correct for the following fact

$\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{J}} (U_\alpha \cap Y) = (\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{J}} U_\alpha)\cap Y$.

let $x \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{J}} (U_\alpha \cap Y) \iff \exists \alpha \in \mathbb{J} \ : \ x \in U_{\alpha}\ and\ x \in Y \iff x \in (\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{J}} U_\alpha)\cap Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and not. You are skipping some steps which are trivial but which I would most definitely consider writing down in a complete solution. My solution would be
\begin{align*}x &\in \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{J}} (U_\alpha \cap Y) \\ 
& \iff\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{J} \ : \ x \in (U_{\alpha}\cap Y)\\
& \iff \exists \alpha \in \mathbb{J} \ :\ \left\{ x \in U_{\alpha}\ \land\ x \in Y \right\}
\\ & \iff \left\{ \exists \alpha \in \mathbb{J} \ : \ x \in U_{\alpha}\ \right\}\land\ x \in Y
 \\ & \iff \left\{x \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{J}} U_\alpha\right\}\land x\in Y
 \\ & \iff x \in \left(\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{J}} U_\alpha\right) \cap Y.
\end{align*}
Maybe the second step and third step are a little bit redundant, but besides that I would most definitely at least put one of them and the fourth one.